# how to stream live m3u8 file using ffmpeg to youtube rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, youtube-livestreaming-api, m3u

i want to restream a live m3u8 file to youtube
.i used following code

```
fmpeg -re -i <http://mypanel.tv:8080/live/****/slyv0955k9/14131.m3u8
> -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv "<rtmp://live-dfw.twitch.tv/app/{live_231566994_FS4BN0qoJMeXEuWklm6j0l1ODQj9u6}>"
```

and i return i get this from my linux server

```
[root@server ~]# ffmpeg -re -i http://mypanel.tv:8080/live/****/slyv0955k9/14131.m3u8
 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv "<rtmp://live-dfw.twitch.tv/app/{live_23156556994_FS4BN0qoJMeXEuWklm6j0l1ODQj9u6}>"ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[h264 @ 0x1029ba0] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x1073680] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://mypanel.tv:8080/live/***/slyv0955k9/14131.m3u8':
  Duration: N/A, start: 39062.400000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 133 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

so can anyone help me with this?please note i'm not an expert in linux so please give me specific commands to restream a live m3u8 file

Answer (score 5):

Try it:

```
#! /bin/bash

PRESET="ultrafast" # ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow, placebo
SOURCE="http://sample.vodobox.net/skate_phantom_flex_4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k.m3u8"
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
KEY="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" # Your youtube key. (https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard > encoder config > name/key)

ffmpeg \
    -re -i "$SOURCE" -vcodec libx264 -preset $PRESET -maxrate 3000k -b:v 2500k \
    -bufsize 600k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 \
    -ar 44100 -f flv -s 1280x720 "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

Comment: This works on the windows builds as well, you just need to fill in the variables or use a batch script. Many thanks!